# Using AGM Map & Google Places API - how can I pass in a latitude and longitude and retrieve the place_id for the nearest native Google Map location?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I need to get location data using Google Places API, but I don't have the `place_id`. All I have is the **latitude** and **longitude** and I need to find the `place_id` of the nearest location that comes loaded in the Google Maps AGM Map (POI).

I've tried `(mapClick)="clicked($event)"` but that only passes in the coordinates. AGM Marker's click event doesn't work because I'm not trying to get info about my own custom markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought apparently AGM team is working on a solution to return the placeId on the mapClick event, I needed an immediate solution. The following is what I did to get the placeId:

**map.component.html:**

```
<agm-map (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)" ... ></agm-map>
```

**map.component.ts:**

```
public onMapReady(map) {
  map.addListener('click', (e) => {
    ...
  });
}
```

In the code above, 'e' is the object that includes a placeId (if the user clicked on a place). If the user didn't click a place, no placeId is returned.

I then use the placeId to call the Google Places Details API to get the data about the place.

I hope this can help someone while we wait for the AGM solution.